# How to find a function with two variables from two functions with one variable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am trying to determine a function for an algorithm I wrote.

The time $t$ it takes to run depends on two variables  $w$ and $l$   (with $l > 0$ and $w > 0$)

I measured $t$ with a fixed $w$ and with different values of $l$ and I found:

$$t =f(l) = 0.0054l$$

Then I measured $t$ with a fixed $l$ and with different values of $w$ and I found 
$$t = g(w) = 0.0029w $$

How can I determine a function $\phi$ with two variables such that: $$t= \phi(w,l)$$

I think that $ f(l) = \frac{\delta \phi}{\delta l}  \text{ and }  g(w) = \frac{\delta \phi}{\delta w} $  but I am not sure and I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that for a fixed value of $w$ $t$ is linear with $l$ and that for a fixed value of $l$ $t$ is linear with $w$, the more general solution of the problem seems to be $$t(w,l)=\alpha +\beta w +\gamma l+\delta wl$$ which is linear in all directions.

Comment: Is there a method to determine the $\alpha , \beta, \gamma , \delta$ values of this function?

Comment: Multilinear regression with $t$ being the dependent variable, $w,l,wl$ being the independent variables.